# How does an outsider's dead body continue to exist in The Matrix?

Tags: the-matrix

In the first movie, Morpheus told Neo in a simulation program that their virtual bodies were mental projection of theirs. That's why they looked like their real world counterparts.

How did then their virtual bodies continue to exist in the Matrix after their real bodies had died? Once the person projecting the mental image was dead and physically removed from the system, why did their corpse remain (and presumably decompose)?

Comment: If I remember correctly, if you die in the Matrix you *do* die in the real world, and vice versa. This happened quite a few times in a first movie.

Comment: @commando I am talking about survival of dead body..

Comment: They didn't. Switch and Apoc died instantly in the Matrix when Cypher killed/unplugged them in the real world.

Comment: @phantom42 Edited the question with more clarity. You understood different thing.

Comment: It's no different. Switch and Apoc died outside of the Matrix and died and their virtual bodies died and dropped out of shot.

Comment: @phantom42 Have you refreshed the page? I am asking why their bodies didn't disappear..

Comment: @SachinShekhar I'm going to edit this question to try and explain what you're asking more clearly; please roll it back if I get it wrong.

Comment: The Matrix is a virtual reality simulator. It virtually simulates the decomposition of the body so people IN the matrix don't suspect they are anywhere but in the real world. The computer simply presents people with the information they are expecting. Though the real person's body may be disconnected from the System, a virtual construct is maintained until whatever rites are needed to be done and then the body and its attendant information are deleted from the System.

Comment: I think you're mistaken - your key point 'their virtual bodies were mental projection of theirs' is wrong.

Comment: @APaleShadow It was said by Morpheus in the 1st movie. You can watch 1st or 2nd non-matrix simulation sessions of Neo.

Comment: @Thaddeus You're right, but system was hacked. And, it was unable to cover the reality. That's why matrix people were able to see disappearing persons!

Comment: @Thaddeus I think you're right, up until the point of deleting the body from the system - The Matrix will still need to continue simulating the body's presence until all components have been destroyed or decomposed into base elements.  Otherwise, this would affect things like archaeological digs and exhumations.

Comment: The matrix has a horrible garbage collection algorithm.

Comment: @fire.eagle Ha.. Ha.. Ha.. It has multiple senses.

Comment: This ain't Tron. One does not simply de-rezz a corpse.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

AFAIK, this issue is never directly addressed in the moves or Animatrix shorts, but the behavior here seems to match exactly what we might expect from a virtual reality simulation.

The residual self-image projected by the individual allows the Matrix to maintain a consistent projection of a connected person that matches what they believe themselves to look like. This image of a connected person changes as they age and grow, and the Matrix needs to allow that image to adapt.

Once the person dies, their image no longer changes according to their mental image of themselves. It now changes according to entirely predictable rules of biology and chemistry. The Matrix will have a "snapshot" of a person's residual self image at the moment of their death. From there it can project the expected decomposition, but in effect, the corpse is no longer an image of a living human, but a "prop" made of organic tissue (in the same way I assume the Matrix produces life-like plants and animals.)

Answer (score 1):

Only people who had already existed in The Matrix were able to be inserted into The Matrix.

Tank and Dozer, for example, had no ports and could not be inserted into the simulation.

Switch and Apoc, on the other hand, had been freed. The simulation already *had* their information in its memory. But being disconnected from the simulation in any way removed them FROM the simulation. When Cypher killed them in the real world, they were removed from the simulation - but the program/simulation still had the information regarding their original appearances, etc.